# stop other function when alert of validation appear

Tags: javascript, jscript

```js
function fuelPrice(form)
{
  "use strict";

    var fuelPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var withFuelPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("ful");
    if(withFuelPrice[form].checked==true)
    {
        fuelPrice=30;
    }
    return fuelPrice;
}

function withPol(form)
{
  "use strict";

    var polishPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var includeInscription = document.getElementsByClassName("pol");
    if(includeInscription[form].checked==true){
        polishPrice=50;
    }
    return polishPrice;
}

function driver(form)
{
    var driverPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var getDriv = document.getElementsByClassName("drv");
    if(getDriv[form].checked==true){
        driverPrice=50;
    }
    return driverPrice;
}

function calculateTotal(form)
{
var car1= 50
    var total = fuelPrice(form) + withPol(form) + car1 + driver(form);
     var text = "Total Price For the Renting "+total+ "BHD/Week";
    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementsByClassName('totalPrice');
    divobj[form].style.display='block';
    divobj[form].innerHTML = text;
  
    return text;
 return total;

}

function myFunction(sel)
{ "use strict";

 var e = document.getElementById("CarList");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 var name = calculateTotal(0);
 var conf = confirm(name);
 if (conf === true){
  alert( strUser + " Added to cart!" );
 }
  else {
  alert("Canceled");
}

 }



function showDiv(elem){
 "use strict";
   if(elem.value === "Toyota"){
    
      document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('hidden_div2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('hidden_div3').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('dispcoin').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('butn').style.display = "block";

    }
 else if (elem.value === "Volvo"){
 document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div2').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('hidden_div3').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('butn').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('dispcoin').style.display = "block";



 }
 else if (elem.value === "Audi"){
 document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div2').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div3').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('butn').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('dispcoin').style.display = "block";


 }
  else if (elem.value === "none"){
 document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div2').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div3').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('butn').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('dispcoin').style.display = "none";

 }
}
function validateForm()
{
  validForm = true;
  var fields = ["firstname", "lastname"]

  var i, l = fields.length;
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    console.log(document.forms["names"]);
    if (document.forms["names"][fieldname].value === ""){
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
           validForm = false;
      return false;

    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="names" >
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Mickey"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Mouse"><br>
    Car Type:<br>

<select id="CarList" onChange="showDiv(this)">
    <option value="none">Choose a Car..</option>
    <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
Color  <input type="color" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000"><br>

Date:<input type="date" name="bday" max="1999-1-1"><br><br>

<p class="totalPrice booktxt" id="dispcoin" style="display: none;">Total Price For the Renting 50BHD/Week<br> </p>
<div id="hidden_div" style="display: none;"><img src="images/6.jpg"/></div>
<div id="hidden_div2" style="display: none;"><img src="images/1.jpg"/></div>
<div id="hidden_div3" style="display: none;"><img src="images/9.jpg"/></div>


   <form class="price">
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="ful">With Fuel<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="pol">Polishing 2 weeks<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="drv">Driver<br>

                </form>
    <input id="butn" type="button" style="display: none;" value="Submit" onClick="validateForm(), myFunction(this), showDiv(this)">
    

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hi
there is an issue that occur. I want to when there is info missing, and the user clicks the submit then the alert appear and user click ok stop other functions.
i tried using {break;}
and window.stop()
so is there is a possible way or i do when user click ok from alert it refreshed.

Comment: what about using a global variable and set it to false when the form is not valid? And use this variable inside your functions.

Comment: @Mils do u mean var stop = false ?

Comment: yes, let's say the variable name is: validForm, you can use it this way inside your function:  function calculateTotal(form){ if(validForm) {// your code } }

Comment: @Mils i did not get it sorry can u do it in snippet

Comment: why your submit button is not displayed?

Comment: @Mils because the user need to choose a car first then it will appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var validForm = true;
function fuelPrice(form)
{
  "use strict";

    var fuelPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var withFuelPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("ful");
    if(withFuelPrice[form].checked==true)
    {
        fuelPrice=30;
    }
    return fuelPrice;
}

function withPol(form)
{
  "use strict";

    var polishPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var includeInscription = document.getElementsByClassName("pol");
    if(includeInscription[form].checked==true){
        polishPrice=50;
    }
    return polishPrice;
}

function driver(form)
{
    var driverPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var getDriv = document.getElementsByClassName("drv");
    if(getDriv[form].checked==true){
        driverPrice=50;
    }
    return driverPrice;
}

function calculateTotal(form)
{
  if(validForm) {
     var car1= 50
    var total = fuelPrice(form) + withPol(form) + car1 + driver(form);
     var text = "Total Price For the Renting "+total+ "BHD/Week";
    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementsByClassName('totalPrice');
    divobj[form].style.display='block';
    divobj[form].innerHTML = text;
  
    return text;
 return total;

 }

}

function myFunction(sel)
{ "use strict";
    if(validForm) {
         var e = document.getElementById("CarList");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 var name = calculateTotal(0);
 var conf = confirm(name);
 if (conf === true){
  alert( strUser + " Added to cart!" );
 }
  else {
  alert("Canceled");
}

    }
 

 }



function showDiv(elem){
 "use strict";
   if(elem.value === "Toyota"){
    
      document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('hidden_div2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('hidden_div3').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('dispcoin').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('butn').style.display = "block";

    }
 else if (elem.value === "Volvo"){
 document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div2').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('hidden_div3').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('butn').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('dispcoin').style.display = "block";



 }
 else if (elem.value === "Audi"){
 document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div2').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div3').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('butn').style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById('dispcoin').style.display = "block";


 }
  else if (elem.value === "none"){
 document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div2').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('hidden_div3').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('butn').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('dispcoin').style.display = "none";

 }
}
function validateForm()
{
  validForm = true;
  var fields = ["firstname", "lastname"]

  var i, l = fields.length;
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    console.log(document.forms["names"]);
    if (document.forms["names"][fieldname].value === ""){
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
           validForm = false;
      return false;

    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="names" >
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Mickey"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Mouse"><br>
    Car Type:<br>

<select id="CarList" onChange="showDiv(this)">
    <option value="none">Choose a Car..</option>
    <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
Color  <input type="color" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000"><br>

Date:<input type="date" name="bday" max="1999-1-1"><br><br>

<p class="totalPrice booktxt" id="dispcoin" style="display: none;">Total Price For the Renting 50BHD/Week<br> </p>
<div id="hidden_div" style="display: none;"><img src="images/6.jpg"/></div>
<div id="hidden_div2" style="display: none;"><img src="images/1.jpg"/></div>
<div id="hidden_div3" style="display: none;"><img src="images/9.jpg"/></div>


   <form class="price">
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="ful">With Fuel<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="pol">Polishing 2 weeks<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="drv">Driver<br>

                </form>
    <input id="butn" type="button" style="display: none;" value="Submit" onClick="validateForm(), myFunction(this), showDiv(this)">
    

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: it still the same

Comment: thank you it worked but can u help me to know what is my mistakes?

Comment: if it works, could accept the appropriate answer, thanks.
You were not calling the global variable (validForm) inside the two functions(calculateTotal and myFunction)
So the content of those functions will be called just when you have a valid form.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
<input id="butn" type="button" style="display: none;" value="Submit" onClick="validateForm(), myFunction(this), showDiv(this)">
```

You should have a single `submit` function. In that function you call your `validateForm` function. If that returns `true` you call you other functions in the order you want to run them.

Comment: Do i need to do a submit function?